# Question of pointer function - Insert pointer function

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void tell_me(int f(int));
int f(int);
int a(int);

void main()
{
    tell_me(a);
}

void tell_me(int (*f)(int))
{
    int x;

    if(f == (*a))
    {
            x = 1;
    }
    else
            x = 2;

    printf("%d\n", f(x));
}

int f(int j) 
{ 
return j * j;
}
int a(int j) 
{ 
return j * 4;
}
```

why this answer is 4?

I'm confused about a.

I think `int a(int) = int (*f) (int)`
so a == *f
and change f to a
so use int a j*4

and int f look like a fake.
because this is one of the exam in my class.

Is my logic correct?

Help me...

Comment: Because `f == (*a)` is true, that means `x` will be assigned the value `1`. Then you call `f(x)` (which is the same as `f(1)` which is the same as `a(1)`) you will get the result `4` back (because `a` return `j * 4` which in this case is `1 * 4` which is `4`).

Comment: Perhaps you might want to refresh your text-books chapters and sections on *scope*? It's always the variables (or functions) in the closest surrounding scope that are used.

Answer (score 1):

## Main problem

[Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) already explained shortly where the value `4` comes from (in the comments to the question). I'll try to explain it in a bit more elaborate way:

First, in the function `main`, after the call `tell_me(a)`, `tell_me` receives the value of `a` as its parameter.

Then, in the function `tell_me`, `f` has the same value as `a`. `*a` is a dereference of a pointer to the function `a`. We know that [[1]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access)

> If pointer-expression is a pointer to function, the result of the dereference operator is a function designator for that function.

and that [[2]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category)

> A function designator (the identifier introduced by a function declaration) is an expression of function type. When used in any context other than the address-of operator, sizeof, and _Alignof (the last two generate compile errors when applied to functions), the function designator is always converted to a non-lvalue pointer to function.

Thus, `*a` is converted to `a`, and the comparison `f == (*a)` is true.

Then, also in the function `tell_me`, the call `f(x)` is equivalent to `a(x)`. So, `a` receives the value of `x` as its parameter, and this value is `1`.

Then, in the function `a`, the parameter `j` has the value `1`. The return value is `j * 4`, which is `4`.

And back to the function `tell_me`, that value is printed.

## Side notes

It is worth to note that you use the identifier `f` for different things. This may be confusing. In the declaration

```c
void tell_me(int f(int));
```

and in the signature

```c
void tell_me(int (*f)(int))
```

the identifier `f` designates the name of a parameter. Worth to note, in the signature it is written in different form than in the declaration. But we know that [[3]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration)

> (...) any parameter of function type is adjusted to the corresponding pointer type:
>
> ```c
> int f(char g(double)); // declares int f(char (*g)(double))
> ```

Then, in the declaration

```c
int f(int);
```

and in the signature

```c
int f(int j)
```

the identifier `f` designates the name of a function.